# Request body empty after posting data to endpoint

Tags: go, gorilla

I'm not sure why the data being posted is not present when running the following curl request:

```
curl --request POST http://localhost:4000 --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{ "hostname": "bbc.co.uk" }'
```

against the code below. It's essentially just posting json with the variable `hostname` but for some reason it's not appearing in `req.Body` or appearing in the `Domain` structure array. Please note this is based on [this tutorial](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/07/create-a-simple-restful-api-with-golang/)

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/gorilla/handlers"
)

type Domain struct {
    hostname string   `json:"hostname,omitempty"`
}

var domains []Domain

func CreateDomainEndpoint(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    var domain Domain

    fmt.Println(req.Body)
    _ = json.NewDecoder(req.Body).Decode(&domain)
    domains = append(domains, domain)
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(domains)
}

func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/", CreateDomainEndpoint).Methods("POST")

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":4000", handlers.CORS(handlers.AllowedHeaders([]string{"X-Requested-With", "Content-Type", "Authorization"}), handlers.AllowedMethods([]string{"GET", "POST", "PUT", "HEAD", "OPTIONS"}), handlers.AllowedOrigins([]string{"*"}))(router)))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The JSON codec ignores the `hostname` field because the field is not [exported](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers). Fix by capitalizing the name of the field.
- There is a data race on `domains`.  Fix by protecting access to the variable with a [mutex](https://godoc.org/sync#Mutex).
- The application ignores errors. Fix by checking for and handing the error returned from the JSON decoder.

Here's the code with fixes:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "sync"

    "github.com/gorilla/handlers"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

type Domain struct {
    Hostname string `json:"hostname,omitempty"`
}

var (
    domains []Domain
    mu      sync.Mutex
)

func CreateDomainEndpoint(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    var domain Domain
    if err := json.NewDecoder(req.Body).Decode(&domain); err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "bad request", 400)
        return
    }
    mu.Lock()
    domains = append(domains, domain)
    // To avoid holding the mutex while writing to the
    // response body, make a local copy of the slice header.
    d := domains
    mu.Unlock()

    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(d)
}

func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/", CreateDomainEndpoint).Methods("POST")

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":4000", handlers.CORS(handlers.AllowedHeaders([]string{"X-Requested-With", "Content-Type", "Authorization"}), handlers.AllowedMethods([]string{"GET", "POST", "PUT", "HEAD", "OPTIONS"}), handlers.AllowedOrigins([]string{"*"}))(router)))
}
```